# 'Counting' the number of records that match a certain criteria and displaying the numbers (using PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database containing a user's country and whether they are an individual or an organisation. The field names are 'country' and 'type'.

Using PHP, I'd like to 'count' the number of countries, the number of individuals and the number of organisations in the database and then display the numbers in the following example format:

```
<p>So far, <strong>500</strong> individuals and <strong>210</strong> organisations from <strong>40</strong> countries have registered their support.</p>
```

I am currently listing the total number of records using the below code if this helps:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("database_name", $link);        
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name", $link);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);        
    echo "&nbsp;$num_rows\n ";  
?>
```

My PHP / MySQL skills are very limited so I'm really struggling with this one.

Many thanks in advance!

Ben

Comment: What do you have already (php / sql)?

Comment: it's mysql skills you need to get these numbers

Comment: I currently just list the total number of records in the database, which is about as far as my PHP skills go I'm afraid: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database", $link); $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); echo "&nbsp;$num_rows\n ";

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, I did mean to say PHP / MySQL skills.

Comment: I have updated my initial query to include the code I'm currently using to display the number of all records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a count based on a grouping. Try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT type, count(*) as cnt FROM users GROUP BY type";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$counts = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $counts[$row['type']] = $row['cnt'];
}
```

This will give you an array like

```
Array (
    'individual' => 500,
    'organization' => 210
)
```

For counting the countries, use the first statement as [posted by Hammerite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433387/counting-the-number-of-records-that-match-a-certain-criteria-and-displaying-the/5433486#5433486).

---

***EDIT***: added a verbose example for counting the countries

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT country) AS NumCountries FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$number_of_countries = 0;
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $number_of_countries = $row['NumCountries'];
}
```

---

This altogether you can then print out:

```
printf('<p>So far, <strong>%d</strong> individuals and <strong>%d</strong> '.
       'organisations from <strong>%d</strong> countries have registered '.
       'their support.</p>', $counts['individual'], $counts['organization'],
        $number_of_countries);
```

Comment: Wow, massively detailed. Thank you very much. I will try and implement the statement posted by Hammerite alongside this as you suggest.

Comment: Hi again Cassy. I'm so close thanks to this code you have provided! I have managed to output the number of individuals and organisations, but I'm struggling with the countries. I'm just not sure where to put Hammerite's MySQL statement and how to link it up with the '$number_of_countries' variable in your printf statement. Are you able to help?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! Thank you so much for all of your help. That works absolutely perfectly. If only I could vote up.

Answer (score 4):

To get the number of countries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT country) AS NumCountries FROM tableName
```

To get the number of individuals, or the number of organisations:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumIndividuals FROM tableName WHERE type = 'individual'
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumOrganisations FROM tableName WHERE type = 'organisation'
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. As Cassy suggests, I will try and implement this alongside the code he has provided.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to retrieve the answer by using the COUNT(*) function in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS individual_count FROM user WHERE type = 'individual';
SELECT COUNT(*) AS organization_count FROM user WHERE type = 'organization';
SELECT COUNT(*) AS country_count FROM user GROUP BY country;
```

The last will group your query set by the country name, and will result in one row for each country. Using COUNT on this result set will give the count of distinct coutries.

You can then fetch this value by using mysql_fetch_assoc on your $result from mysql_query, and the answer will be contained in 'invididual_count', 'organization_count' and 'country_count' for each query.

Comment: That's also very useful thank you. With all of the answers that have been provided, I will do my best to get this working now!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help with this (especially Cassy).

I think it's worthwhile displaying the full code in case anybody else comes across a similar requirement in the future:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database_name", $link);

$sql = "SELECT type, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table_name GROUP BY type";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$counts = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $counts[$row['type']] = $row['cnt'];
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT country) AS NumCountries FROM table_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);                
$number_of_countries = 0;
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $number_of_countries = $row['NumCountries'];
}

printf('<p><strong>So far, <em class="count">%d</em> individuals and <em class="count">%d</em> organisations from <em class="count">%d</em> countries have registered their support.', $counts['Individual'], $counts['Organisation'], $number_of_countries); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're just looking for the number of rows returned try this:

```
$result = mysql_db_query($db, $query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Another option would be to execute a separate query with the mysql count function and use the result from that.

Comment: nope, he isn't looking for the number of rows returned. he is looking for just one row